# How to threshold a specific color in OpenGL/GLSL

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, openframeworks, blending

I made a particle trail effect in OpenGL.

The trick is to draw a semi transparent rectangle on the screen to gradually fade the previous frame:

```
    ofSetColor(0,0,0,255*(1.0-persistence));
    ofFill();
    ofRect(0, 0, ofGetScreenWidth(), ofGetScreenHeight());
```

and then draw the particles (roughly):

```
    ofEnableBlendMode(OF_BLENDMODE_ADD);    
    ofEnablePointSprites();
    vbo.draw(GL_POINTS, 0, (int)points.size());
    ofDisablePointSprites();
```

[image: Particle trails effect]

The problem is that the trails do not fade until being pure black, but remain grayish.

I could threshold the dark gray values, or fade them progressively, but what is the best way to do it? OpenGL blending functions/operations or shader? Speed is a major concern.

Comment: What blend mode are you using? If you're using the default, you could try multiplicative or subtractive blending instead.

Comment: http://www.openframeworks.cc/documentation/graphics/ofGraphics.html#show_ofEnableBlendMode

Comment: I suppose that you mean when I draw the transparent rectangle. Could you explain why you advise a different blend mode? What will it change? I don't remember how blendMode affect the final fragment.

Comment: My suspicion is that it's roundoff error, e.g. the fragment colour becomes something small like 0.01, which gets multiplied by your fade (say 0.9) to get 0.09. But when that's stored back into a byte (using a regular RGBA8 framebuffer), it might get rounded back up to 0.01. (Actual values not correct; for illustration only.) Actually multiplicative blending wouldn't help, but subtracting instead of multiplying might do the trick. (Subtract something non-black of course :))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to allocate your fbo with a floating point format.

There is an example in openFrameworks examples directory that shows the difference between floating point and non floating point format and it seems to be your problem (`examples/gl/fboTrailsExample`).

Allocation with a floating point format:

```
ofFbo rgbaFboFloat;
rgbaFboFloat.allocate(400, 400, GL_RGBA32F_ARB);
```

and then in the update method you can draw to the fbo between `rgbaFboFloat.begin();` and `rgbaFboFloat.end();`

To finish, you draw your fbo in the draw method: `rgbaFboFLoat.draw(0,0);`

Comment: Thanks, I feel ashamed because I already had and solved this problem, but I did not remember correctly the solution. What I did is try ```window.setGlutDisplayString("rgba double samples>=4");``` in main.cpp but without success (I though it would create a float fbo directly for the screen, but apparently it does something different...) Also, when I tried with double FBO, I forgot to clear the screen (```ofBackground(0,0,0,0)```) before drawing the FBO (which does the same thing, but with the trails!). Maybe you should at this in your answer as a reminder.

Comment: I would also like to know how to threshold a color with OpenGL. This might be faster since using a second fbo is costly. I opened another [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24852334/719276) marked as duplicate (but it seems it is not an exact duplicate).

Comment: Maybe you could use a fragment shader

Comment: This would also require an FBO. I was thinking of a solution with the stencil buffer.